# PHP compare Fail?

Tags: php, compare

I have the following code which Compares!

```
function arr($part){
    $partt=intval($part);

    if($partt==1){
        $url="x4";
    }if($partt==2){
        $url="x3";
    }if($partt==3){
        $url="x2";
    }if($partt==4){
        $url="x1";
    }else{
        // This always executes
        echo $partt;
        exit;
    }
```

I have tried the following

```
arr(1)
arr('1')
arr("1")
arr((1))
```

all executes this

```
echo $partt;
    exit;
```

This does echo `1` but if $part is `1` then why `$url="x4";` is not executing and why `else` is executing

Comment: You have to use `else if`

Comment: Why so many same answers!!!???

Comment: @testrtq: when a question is easy, people rush to post their own answer and don't have time to read what's already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `else if` like

```
if($partt==1){

    $url="x4";
}else if($partt==2){

    $url="x3";
}else if($partt ==3){

    $url="x2";
}else if($partt==4){

    $url="x1";
}else{

    echo $partt;
    exit;
}
echo $url;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The else will always execute when `$partt` is not equal to `4` because you need to use an `else if`. Your code should look like this:

```
function arr($part){
    $partt=intval($part);

    if($partt==1)
    {
        $url="x4";
    }
    else if($partt==2) 
    {
        $url="x3";
    }
    else if($partt==3) 
    {
        $url="x2";
    }
    else if($partt==4)
    {
        $url="x1";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $partt;
    }
}
```

An even better solution for this would be to use a switch statement:

```
function arr($part) {
    $partt=intval($part);

    switch ($partt)
    {
        case 1:
            $url="x4";
            break;

        case 2:
            $url="x3";
            break;

        case 3:
            $url="x2";
            break;

        case 4:
            $url="x1";
            break;

        default: 
            echo $partt;
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code :

```
if($partt==4){

$url="x1";


}else{
// This always executes
echo $partt;
exit;

}
```

PHP will enter the "else" block if $partt != 4. You should try replacing all "if" but the first one by "elseif".

PHP Documentation : http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use more than one `elseif` try using  `switch` instead.

```
function arr( $part ){
  $partt = intval( $part );

  switch( $partt ){
    case 1:
      $url = "x4";
      break;

    case 2:
      $url = "x3";
      break;

    case 3:
      $url = "x2";
      break;

    case 4:
      $url = "x1";
      break;

    default:
      echo $partt;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `elseif`

```
function arr($part){
    $partt=intval($part);

    if($partt==1){
        $url="x4";
    }
    elseif($partt==2){
        $url="x3";
    }
    elseif($partt==3){
        $url="x2";
    }
    elseif($partt==4){
        $url="x1";
    }
    else{
        echo $partt;
        exit;
        }
    return $url;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `else if`. Your else was running when `$partt != 4`

```
function arr($part)
{
    $partt = intval($part);

    if ($partt == 1) {
        $url = "x4";
    } else if($partt == 2) {
        $url = "x3";
    } else if($partt == 3) {
        $url = "x2";
    } else if($partt == 4) {
        $url = "x1";
    } else {
        echo $partt;
        exit;
    }
}
```